# Changing the body of html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an Ajax call which returns html body. I'm trying to change the html of the child element by following code:

```
(function inbox() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5958/myaccount/inbox/',
        success: function (data) {
            var x = $(data).find("#refresh")[0];
            $(x).html("f");
            console.log($(x).html())
            //console.log($(data).find("#refresh")[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

How do I change the body of the element "refresh"?
I'm a beginner with jQuery and I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what are you getting on your console?

Comment: @roullie I'm getting "f" in the console but that doesn't change the html of the element "refresh".

Answer (score 3):

Please try this below code

```
success: function (data) {
$("#refresh").html(data); }
```

or

```
success: function (data) {
$('body').find("#refresh").html(data);}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just you need**

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#refresh").html(data);
}
```

This code will change element with id refresh with returned data

**About your code let me explain some things in your code**

```
$(data).find("#refresh")[0]; // I really don't know why you use [0] here
```

that mean data returned html with element has id refresh .. so data looks like

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div id="refresh">
       refresh data here
   </div>
</div>
```

so your code in success

```
var x = $(data).find("#refresh");
```

x will return an object

```
x = '<div id="refresh">refresh data here</div>';
```

and after that you used

```
$(x).html("f");
```

that mean you change x again to be

```
x = '<div id="refresh">f</div>';
```

so after you use

```
console.log($(x).html());
```

it will return `f` and this is right

but all your code not appended anything to your html page yet so you should use

```
$("body").html(x); // this will change body html to f
```

Comment: i think he wants to change something on the return variable `data`

Comment: @roullie I thought that too .. till I read (How do I change the body of the element "refresh"? )

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef appreciate your help but that's not what I'm trying to do. By saying $("#refresh").html(data); will replace the html of "refresh" with data when I'm only trying to change the html of an element within data. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Just saw the edit. $("body").html(x); will replace the body element with "f". I'm trying to only replace the html of "refresh" with "f".

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba you can use $("#refresh").html(x);

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something line this : '<div id="refresh">f</div>';

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba look Ahmed that is depending on where <div id="refresh">  is .. is it already in say (index page) or its part from returned html data ??

Comment: it's part of the returned html data.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba seems I got your point .. you need to change refresh html with f  before you append all data in your html .. right??

Answer (score 0):

Make a blank div in the body like `<div id="result"></div>`

Then in success of the ajax :

`success : function(data){`

```
      value = data.value; // get whatever value you want from data

      $("#result").html(value);

      }
```